# Setting MongoDb to change a property to UpperCase

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following poco (other properties omitted for simplicity) :

```
public class Address
{
   . . .    
  public string CountryCode { get; set; }
   . . .
}
```

What do I have to do in the `BsonClassMap` to enforce Upper Case only for this property.
For Example "us" will be stored in the db as "US"

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Address>(cm =>
            {
               // what am I missing here ?
            });
```

Or am I approaching this the wrong way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a custom serializer attribute you can decorate the country code property with:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UpperCaseAttribute : BsonSerializerAttribute
{
    public UpperCaseAttribute() : base(typeof(UpperCaseSerializer)) { }

    private class UpperCaseSerializer : SerializerBase<string>
    {
        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext ctx, BsonSerializationArgs args, string value)
        {
            if (value is null)
                ctx.Writer.WriteNull();
            else
                ctx.Writer.WriteString(value.ToUpper());
        }

        public override string Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext ctx, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            switch (ctx.Reader.CurrentBsonType)
            {
                case BsonType.String:
                    return ctx.Reader.ReadString();

                case BsonType.Null:
                    ctx.Reader.ReadNull();
                    return null;

                default:
                    throw new BsonSerializationException($"'{ctx.Reader.CurrentBsonType}' values are not valid on properties decorated with an [UpperCase] attribute!");
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:

```cs
public class Address
{
  [UpperCase]  
  public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I think a custom serializer is the way !

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

1. `SetElementName` way:

   ```
   BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Address>(cm =>
   {
       cm.MapField(e => e.CountryCode).SetElementName("COUNTRY_CODE");
   });
   var address = new Address();
   var bson = address.ToBsonDocument();  
   // bson: { "COUNTRY_CODE" : null }
   ```
2. `BsonElement` attribute way:

   ```
   public class Address
   {
       [BsonElement("COUNTRY_CODE")]
       public string CountryCode { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you answer dododo. I guess the question was a bit misleading, I have updated it. I was looking for how to convert the value of Country Code to upper case and store it in db, not property name.

Comment: idk a way for this (not sure that it's possible), you can always implement a custom serializer for this logic: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/serialization/