# How to compare string and date-time in expression using EF Core MongoDB driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework-core

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Parse({document}{processeddate}) is
> not supported.'

The exception was thrown on the line following.

```
result = trackCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(x => DateTime.Parse(x.ProcessedDate) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3))
    .ToList();
```

```
public class Track
{
    [BsonElement("processeddate")]
    public string ProcessedDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

`processeddate` is a string in MongoDB collection.

How to compare string and date time in `Match` expression using EFCore MongoDB driver?

Although it works I don't prefer this way due to performance issues:

```
result = trackCollection.Aggregate()
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.ProcessedDate) > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. You can define your POCO property like:

   ```
   [BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.String)]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   ```

which will allow you to work with DateTime on the c# side and a simple string in mongo document. All magic will happen in serialization steps.

2. I don't think that it's possible via any other typed way, however it's supported on MQL level, see: [Possible to compare date strings in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546790/possible-to-compare-date-strings-in-mongodb). Also in raw MQL you can use $[toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

So you should either create your `match` stage as a raw MQL string with fields definitions as in the mongo document like:

```
  ... 
  .Match("raw MQL $match query")
  ...
```

or you can transform a string representation of date into mongo date in the stage before $match via $[project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or $[addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). Then in $match stage you will have already converted date value

Comment: First option: FormatException was thrown with this message: An error occurred while deserializing the Date property of class ...Track: String '2021-10-06 11:53:29' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Second option: I can't implement that because of my mongodb version (v3.2.9) does not support `$toDate`, `$dateFromString` operators.

Comment: First option: then you may need to implement a custom serializer (for example via `BsonSerializerAttribute`) similar to how it's done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67128708/setting-mongodb-to-change-a-property-to-uppercase/67129599#67129599

Comment: Second option: you still can use `new Date(processedDate)`, I'm not sure off the top of my head how it can be done on so old server, but you may look at $find-projection or $where https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/